# Console error testing effort reduction needed

Tags: browser, automation, console.log

I had been working on automating the console testing for a website. As manually it is very time taking to go and check for consoled errors using browser dev tools for all the pages. For eg a website with 200 navigation links is too much manual effort and time consuming.
Using web driver is a potential solution but not in our case depending on requirements and resources.
I was hoping it could pull the console errors in the website log and then configure a notification but I'm unable to pull up the console error in the log.
Any help/solution for pulling up the errors in log?
Or may be any better solution for automating it all together?

Answer (score 1):

You can use below code to get the browser logs (Note : Chrome with selenium Java)

```
    LogEntries logEntries = driver.manage().logs().get(LogType.BROWSER);
    for (LogEntry entry : logEntries) {
        System.out.println(new Date(entry.getTimestamp()) + " " + entry.getLevel() + " " + entry.getMessage());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to get a browser to visit 200+ links that's somehow faster than a script on a headless browser. So the question makes little sense because it's not *automation* unless you're doing something automated.

Another approach would be to use a javascript error reporting tool like [Sentry](https://sentry.io/).